# Not able to Parse json using Gson if json string don't have key name

Tags: android, json, gson

I have below json string but not able to parse. Can anyone help. Thanks in advance.

```
{
  [ 
    {"transaction_name" : "total_fare", "unit" : "Rs", "label" : "Bill Amount", "value" : 250, "additional_details" : "4 Rides"}, 
    {"transaction_name" : "incentives", "label" : "Incentives", "value" : 50, "additional_details" : ""},
    {"transaction_name" : "fees", "label" : "Fees", "value" : -20, "additional_details" : "Rs 5 on each ride"},
    {"transaction_name" : "device_deduction", "label" : "Device Deduction", "value" : -20, "additional_details" : ""},
    {"transaction_name" : "tax", "label" : "Device Deduction", "value" : -20, "additional_details" : ""},
    {"transaction_name" : "device_deduction", "label" : "Device Deduction", "value" : -20, "additional_details" : ""}]
  ],
  "footer" : 
    {
      "transaction_name" : "total_earning_net", "label" : "Total Earnings", "value" : 200, 
      "additional_details" : "Rounding Off"
    }
}
```

Comment: You should provide the code you're trying to parse with and the specific errors you are encountering. See [MCVE] and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @pvg I am not able to right code. I am facing problem because inner json array don't have key.

Comment: Problem is your JSON string is not valid JSON. Where is the key??

Comment: @ColdFire in my json one field don't have key

Comment: @ShrikantSalunkhe not sure this is a programming question, then and this is a site for programming questions.

Comment: it is not a valid json then

Comment: i have corrected your json format use this format and then try to parse or share your code for getting help.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON itself is wrong, try to give a key to your JSONArray,

```
{
"data": [{
    "transaction_name": "total_fare",
    "unit": "Rs",
    "label": "Bill Amount",
    "value": 250,
    "additional_details": "4 Rides"
}, {
    "transaction_name": "incentives",
    "label": "Incentives",
    "value": 50,
    "additional_details": ""
}, {
    "transaction_name": "fees",
    "label": "Fees",
    "value": -20,
    "additional_details": "Rs 5 on each ride"
}, {
    "transaction_name": "device_deduction",
    "label": "Device Deduction",
    "value": -20,
    "additional_details": ""
}, {
    "transaction_name": "tax",
    "label": "Device Deduction",
    "value": -20,
    "additional_details": ""
}, {
    "transaction_name": "device_deduction",
    "label": "Device Deduction",
    "value": -20,
    "additional_details": ""
}],
"footer": {
    "transaction_name": "total_earning_net",
    "label": "Total Earnings",
    "value": 200,
    "additional_details": "Rounding Off"
  }

}
```